# rails3 rc1 with prototype and jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

I have a rails3 project where I need to use prototype together with jquery - using the current Ruby on Rails 3 RC1 there is no example or documentation to use both together without problems.

Is there a setup instruction or did anyone get both javascript frameworks running with the latest rails version?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried jQuery.noConflict()? I'm running a Rails 3 rc app with both Prototype and jQuery using the no conflict function - the jQuery bit is working fine, not too sure about Prototype at the moment though.

Add jQuery.noConflict(); to your application.js file - that gives control of the $ call back to Prototype, so jQuery calls have to be tagged with 'jQuery', rather than '$' eg. jQuery.getJSON instead of $.getJSON. Alternatively, you could define a variable: var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); - the previous example would then become $j.getJSON. Finally, you can also keep jQuery code with $ whilst using jQuery.noConflict() by wrapping it in another function:

```
(function($) {
//your code in here
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thanks for your comment! can you please be more specific? where did you set jQuery.noConflict() and what is your load order of the libraries?

Comment: I've updated my comment to be a bit more specific, hope that helps!